# Function for multiple T-test to find main effect

Tags: r, statistics

```
df <- data.frame (rating1  = c(1,5,2,4,5),
                  rating2  = c(2,1,2,4,2),
                  rating3  = c(0,2,1,2,0),
              race = c("black", "asian", "white","black","white"),
              gender = c("male","female","female","male","female")
              )
```

I'd like to conduct t-test of group mean (e.g. mean of asians in rating1) and the overall mean of each rating (e.g. rating1). Below is my code for Asians in rating1.

```
asian_df <- df %>% 
   filter(race == "asian")
t.test(asian_df$rating1, mean(df$rating1))
```

Then for Blacks in rating 2, I'd run

```
   black_df <- df %>% 
       filter(race == "black")
    t.test(black_df$rating2, mean(df$rating2))
```

How can I write a function that automates the t-test for each group? So far I have to manually change the variable name to essentially run for each race, each gender and on each rating (rating 1 to rating 3).  Thanks!

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense to me - t tests are used for comparing groups, not for comparing one group with the mean of another group. Perhaps this question is better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To clarify, here I am comparing the mean of one group in one condition (e.g. rating 1) against the mean of that condition. And would like to run the test for each group in each condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing multiple t-tests increases your risk of Type I error and you will need to [adjust for multiple comparisons](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5506159/) in order for your results to be valid/meaningful. You can run the t-tests by looping through your variables, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame (rating1  = c(5,8,7,8,9,6,9,7,8,5,8,5),
                  rating2  = c(2,7,8,4,9,3,6,1,7,3,9,1),
                  rating3  = c(0,6,1,2,7,2,9,1,6,2,3,1),
                  race = c("asian", "asian", "asian","black","asian","black","white","black","white","black","white","black"),
                  gender = c("male","female","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female","male")
)

for (rac in unique(df$race)){
tmp_df <- df %>% 
    filter(race == rac)
print(rac)
print(t.test(tmp_df$rating1,
         rep(mean(df$rating1),
             length(tmp_df$rating1))))
}
[1] "asian"

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  tmp_df$rating1 and rep(mean(df$rating1), length(tmp_df$rating1))
t = 0.19518, df = 3, p-value = 0.8577
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.550864  2.884198
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 7.250000  7.083333 

[1] "black"

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  tmp_df$rating1 and rep(mean(df$rating1), length(tmp_df$rating1))
t = -1.5149, df = 4, p-value = 0.2044
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.5022651  0.7355985
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 6.200000  7.083333 

[1] "white"

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  tmp_df$rating1 and rep(mean(df$rating1), length(tmp_df$rating1))
t = 3.75, df = 2, p-value = 0.06433
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1842176  2.6842176
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 8.333333  7.083333 


for (gend in unique(df$gender)){
  tmp_df <- df %>% 
    filter(gender == gend)
  print(gend)
  print(t.test(tmp_df$rating1,
               rep(mean(df$rating1),
                   length(tmp_df$rating1))))
}
[1] "male"

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  tmp_df$rating1 and rep(mean(df$rating1), length(tmp_df$rating1))
t = -2.0979, df = 5, p-value = 0.09
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.4107761  0.2441094
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 6.000000  7.083333 

[1] "female"

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  tmp_df$rating1 and rep(mean(df$rating1), length(tmp_df$rating1))
t = 3.5251, df = 5, p-value = 0.01683
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2933469 1.8733198
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 8.166667  7.083333
```

Due to multiple testing (in this example, 5 t-tests) your chance of a false positive is `1 - (1 - 0.05)^5 = 22.62%` <- very high. To account for this, you can apply the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction), which basically takes your required p-value (in this case, p < 0.05) and divides it by the number of tests (i.e. the new p-value required to reject the null is p < 0.01). When you apply this correction, even the 'best' t-test result (gender; p-value = 0.01683) is not statistically significant.

An alternative approach would be to compare means in all conditions using ANOVA, then use Tukey's HSD to determine which groups are different. Tukey's HSD is a single post-hoc test, so you don't need to account for multiple testing, and your results are valid. Adapting this approach to your problem might be a better way to go e.g.

```
anova_one_way <- aov(rating1 + rating2 + rating3 ~ race + gender, data = df)

summary(anova_one_way)

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
race         2 266.70  133.35   14.01 0.00243 **
gender       1 140.08  140.08   14.72 0.00497 **
Residuals    8  76.13    9.52           
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


TukeyHSD(anova_one_way)

Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = rating1 + rating2 + rating3 ~ race + gender, data = df)

$race
                 diff        lwr       upr     p adj
black-asian -7.050000 -12.963253 -1.136747 0.0224905
white-asian  4.416667  -2.315868 11.149201 0.2076254
white-black 11.466667   5.029132 17.904201 0.0023910

$gender
                 diff       lwr       upr     p adj
male-female -3.416667 -7.523829 0.6904958 0.0913521
```